# gigabit ethernet not working

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi

I connected my laptop (having 1Gbit/s ethernet interface) with raspberry pi 4B (also has 1Gbit/s ethernet interface) using a CAT5E cable (no router/hub). I'm able to see only 100Mbit/s bandwidth (using iperf3). What could be the problem here?

On laptop

```
$ sudo lshw -C Network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 52:05:db:b6:bf:5a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b3204000-b3204fff memory:b3200000-b3203fff
```

On RPi 4B

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lshw -C Network
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: dc:a6:32:ae:b8:9d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.10.63-v7l+ duplex=full ip=169.254.62.244 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
```

I tried setting speed to 1000 manually using

```
sudo ethtool -s <ethernet_interface> speed 1000 duplex full
```

After doing this, the connection disconnects and ethernet lights on the port turn on and off intermittently.

Comment: You have not said, but you need to set speed & duplex on both ends. If that does not work, then perhaps you have a bad cable.

Comment: I did set the speed and full duplex on both ends. Is there any way in which I check my cable without using sophisticated hardware? Like a software signal tester through the cable?

Comment: Having similar issue:   

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.18.16-zen1 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s

Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: yes, it was a bad cable. I was able to get 1000Mbit/s with a new CAT6 cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to a bad cable as mentioned by [Bid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/433674/bib). I checked again with a new CAT6 cable and was able to get much higher bandwidth than 100Mbit/s.